# Conceptual Ideas - Memory is limited for an application but need to pass more data

Tags: c, memory-management

I have a situation as followed - (because of IP-right I cannot share technical details)

There are few individual embedded applications running as a part of a whole project.
Any of these applications can occpy maximum 9000 MB (9GB) of memory.
I am upgrading some application as per new requirement.
There are few tables with buffer length 32767 in each application with is passed to a network server for calculation using 15KHz frequency.
I need to make it double ie 65534 that will be passed to the network at the rate of 30KHz frequency.
The problem arises here -
One of these applications occupy 8094 MB (8GB+) so doubling the table buffer length goes beyond the maximum size of the application. 
As a result the application output does not appear (but there is no crash).

My question is have you ever overcome such problem, could you share some idea how can I do memory management in this particular case? All these programs are written in cpp, perl, c and python (VxWorks, Linux, sunsolaris OS are used).

A quick reply is highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Too vague I'm afraid. You need to be more specific.

Comment: Did you consider memory mapped files? Another possibility is to stream data instead of loading the whole thing in memory..

Answer (score 0):

It is very vague, but I'll try to answer to the point:

If your program needs larger tables due to whatever reasons, but cannot occupy more memory, you have to change something to compensate that.

You don't mention why you need larger tables:

- If the length of the records has increased, try to reduce their number.
- If you then can store a fewer number of entries, you'll have to send them quicker so that you don't have to store so much of them.

What you can do as well is do some compressing in RAM. That is dependent on the nature of the data, but in general, this might help you.

Comment: Doubling the paging size was my idea. but, compressing RAM data I will try, tables consist of Multi-sine injection data for metro-logical calculation, passed to a server for force to sensor frame  measurement inside a machine that is moving in 6 degree of freedom. Data will be saved in matlab file in the end. Design constraint got 4000 MB memory usages for every process. As the table size is increased, data cannot be written directly in one go in a matlab file. I tried to introduce XML to store intermediate data and then convert it to matlab file format later; but, file type is not supported.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I am trying to compress RAM data